# Consider three sets A, B and C When do we have BXAXC=(BXA)XC?

Tags: products

I am stuck on this math question :

Consider three sets $A, B$ and $C$. When do we have $B\times A\times C=(B\times A)\times C$?

I know we have to use Cartesian product to solve this question.

Comment: Welcome. In my experience, $B\times A\times C$ is only well defined because, *up to isomorphism* (which is a trivial one that everyone usually ignores) $(B\times A)\times C\cong B\times(A\times C)$, so $B\times A\times C$ is more-or-less unambiguous. However in the context of your question a precise constructive definition of the triple product is required, since your question is all about: “when is that isomorphism a direct equality?” I can guess how you define it, but I shouldn’t have to!

Comment: After all, perhaps you meant: “when do we have: $(B\times A)\times C=B\times(A\times C)$?”